# Ruckus wireless AP and Dell PowerConnect configuration problems

Tags: networking, wifi, vlan, dell-powerconnect

We are working on trying to get some Ruckus Access Points to work correctly on our network. Currently our network is as follows:

VLAN 10 - Servers
VLAN 11 – Computers/DHCP
VLAN 12 – Voice
VLAN 13 – Guest
We use Dell PowerConnect 6248P switches for our switches.

Port settings are as follows:
ZoneDirector 1100 is plugged into this port. Should be accessing the server VLAN and then allowing all other traffic.

interface ethernet 1/g2
classofservice trust ip-dscp
description 'Ruckus ZoneDirector 1100'
switchport mode general
switchport general pvid 10
switchport general allowed vlan add 10
switchport general allowed vlan add 11-13 tagged
exit

Access point is plugged into this port. The port has to be on VLAN 11 in order to get DHCP.

interface ethernet 1/g16
classofservice trust ip-dscp
description 'Ruckus - IT'
switchport mode general
switchport general pvid 11
switchport general allowed vlan add 10-12
switchport general allowed vlan add 13 tagged
exit

If we tag the traffic from the SSID as VLAN 11 data fails. If we leave the SSID tagged as 1 the data flows correctly.

Are there problems with passing tagged traffic to untagged ports? We are looking to see what we can do to get the SSID tagged as 11 instead of 1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be behaving as expected.

Your access point (unless configured otherwise) is talking to the controller / network with untagged frames (traffic that isn't associated with any particular VLAN). In this case, it's talking on VLAN 11 (the configured PVID on it's port).

As the traffic from the AP is getting pushed onto VLAN 11 (and will be tagged with this VLAN when it egresses the switch), devices on that VLAN will be able to receive it, but only if their port is either untagged on VLAN 11 (has a PVID of 11) or is carrying tagged traffic for VLAN 11 and the client is configured to look for tagged traffic.

The controller is on a port that is configured to carry tagged traffic for VLAN 11, so will drr traffic from the VLAN. If the two are talking as you report, it suggests the controller has an interface which is associated with VLAN 11 and listens to the tagged traffic arriving on that port.

The reason it breaks when you switch port g16 to be tagged for VLAN 11 is that the access point isn't tagging it's traffic, so the switch won't egress it to a specific VLAN.

Comment: We have found that since the PVID of the port was 11 and we were trying to tag the traffic as 11 it was not working. We have been able to get any other SSID to be tagged as a different VLAN to correctly work on its own assigned VLAN. This was new to me so seemed strange that we had to leave at VLAN 1.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you open a case with Ruckus at their support site https://support.ruckuswireless.com/

At a glance it Looks like you are setting the port mode wrong. I "think" it should be mode trunk and not general.

The way I read that configuration it looks like you are setting one vlan (vlan 11) as the general port vlan.  That would explain why a tag of 1 works.

Give it a try with port mode trunk and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding **switchport mode general**.
Instead use **switchport trunk mode** and then **switchport trunk native vlan** *vlan-id*